# where should I put executed HQL result?

Tags: java, hql

I have a HQL join query but I don't know how to execute it. I mean that I don't know where should I put the result in which data type.
the result set is an array of String and Date types.
I want to use an array list with size 2. first position for int and second for date.
please help

Comment: Did you try reading the hibernate documentation from the start? I have the feeling you don't understand its purpose.

Comment: You start by Mapping your classes. Read the documentation about how to do mapping in Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

The result of HQL query is usually a list of some object. Also HQL give you posibility to create a list of some new objects during runnig query, something like:

```
select new SomeObject(something.arg1,something.arg2,something.arg3) from Somewhere as something
```

But check HQL documentation for more details, this should be an idea how to solve your problem.

[Documentation about HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)